# Remove float property of the image when the inline-block move to the bottom of the image

Tags: html, css

I have three elements, one is title, another is paragraph, the other is image. Now, I want the image float to the right, let the title and the paragraph float to the left and bottom, like “Image 1.”

In order not to make the words of the title wrap while narrowing the outer div (the blue frame), I use `display:inline-block` on the title.

But here's the question:
If I narrow the width of the outer div which makes the title move to the bottom of the image, the image is still aligning to the right, like “Image 3.” But what I need is like “Image 2,” the image should align itself to the left.

Is there any way to remove the float property of the image if the inline-block title move to the bottom of the image?

[image]

```css
#div0{
  width: 1000px;
}

#div1{
  width: 550px;
}


.outer{
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.image{
  float: right;
}

.title{
  display: inline-block;
}

.paragraph{
}
```

```html
<div id="div0" class="outer">
    <img src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/eg_tulip.jpg" class="image" />
    <h1 class="title">This Is the Title...</h1>
    <div class="paragraph">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="outer">
    <img src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/eg_tulip.jpg" class="image" />
    <h1 class="title">This Is the Title...</h1>
    <div class="paragraph">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done using CSS alone. The other answers are correct that the best way is to insert a @media query, but in order to know the size of the breakpoint, you have to know the exact widths at runtime. (This depends on lots of factors, so it's not a constant.)

So the way to go is to use some JavaScript to create the media query. This calculates the max-width as the width of the title plus the width of the image plus the width of the border and the outer margin (which I took as 18px).

```js
document.head.innerHTML += '<style>\n'+
  '@media (max-width: '+(document.querySelector('h1.title').offsetWidth+
        document.querySelector('img.image').offsetWidth+18)+'px) {\n'+
  ' .image {float:none}\n'+
  '}\n</style>\n';
```

```css
.outer{
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.image{
  float: right;
}

.title{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div0" class="outer">
    <img src="http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/eg_tulip.jpg" class="image" />
    <h1 class="title">This Is the Title...</h1>
    <div class="paragraph">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:960px) {
    .image{
      float: none;
    }
}
```

You can change the "960px" to the width that you want the change to happen.

Comment: But how should I know the value of the width, if the width is not fixed? (I don't want to use Javascript to solve this problem)

Comment: @BananaCode If you open developer mode in chrome, you'll be able to see the width of your current browser window when resizing. Use that to determine when the image needs to lose its float.

Answer (score 0):

check the value of width in web browsers' Inspect elements.